# Send cron mail using dockerised postfix

Tags: cron, docker, postfix, sendmail, mail-transport-agent

I recently moved postfix into a docker container, with ports 25 and 587 exposed on the host machine.

Since doing this, cron on the host machine is now unable to send emails due to `No MTA installed, discarding output`.

It appears that cron tries to use the `sendmail` command, which is normally provided by an MTA package. Installing postfix on the host to provide sendmail seems a bit silly, and it will try to listen on port 25 and conflict with the mappings from the dockerised postfix.

I tried installing `msmtp` and adding a `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
account default
host localhost
auto_from on
maildomain [domain]
```

Cron now tries to send mail through postfix, but even with the auto_from and maildomain options it seems to use a bare or invalid from header like `From: root` or `From: root (Cron Daemon)`, which gets rejected. opendkim can't handle this either.

I'm assuming that when postfix was installed on the host, the postfix provided `sendmail` sorted out all of the addresses and appended the `mailname` as needed, but that the minimalist msmtp isn't doing this?

What is the solution here? How can I get a sensible `sendmail` command on the host that will use the dockerised postfix to send the mail?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the [`local_header_rewrite_clients`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_header_rewrite_clients) option. The default value is `permit_inet_interfaces`, which only adds the domain for local messages (*source* IP address matches an interface postfix is listening on).

Changing this to `permit_inet_interfaces,permit_mynetworks` allows postfix to also append `myorigin` for anything in `mynetworks` (which in my case includes the docker network in `172.17.0.0/16`).